# Triple integrals over regions containg inequalities

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Example, I understand that $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ represent a  cone in 3-space but what do $z\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $z\ge\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ look like? I can understand that in 2-space that $y\le\sqrt{x}$ gives the region between the curve and the x-axis while $y\ge\sqrt{x}$ gives the region between the curve and the y-axis but I can picture it when it gets kicked up a dimension.

Comment: Think of the cone as an cup, then $\ z<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ $ represents all the volume "contained" within the cone while $\ z>\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ $ represents all the volume "outside" the cone

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think the two simply are the volumes on the two sides of the cone. one inside it and the other outside.

Comment: Got it! Thank you both for the simple and clear explanations.